# Convert a string variable to a date in Python 3?

Tags: python, string, date, python-3.x

Bit of a newbie and I have Google and found no joy with this one.  I am trying to create a bit of code that will allow a user to input a date and then tell them how many days it is until then.  I have tried to convert the string to date.time using strp but I just get an error message.

I want it to run:
user inputs date
message comes up saying there are XX days until.

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There are many examples of python `datetime.strptime` online. If you are getting an error please [edit] your question to include it and the code you've used. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are searching for? You can parse a string to a `datetime` with `strptime`, and then compute the number of days to reach it with `timedelta`.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date = input('Enter your date: ')
delta = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d') - datetime.now()
print("We'll be {} in {} days".format(date, delta.days))
```

You can of course change the accepted format for the date input by the user, which I set to `%Y-%m-%d` in the example here above.